# AsynTask no results on onCreateView of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't understand where is my error. I have a `Fragment` and on `onCreateView` I creat and execute an `AsyncTask`. but it shows no results.

My fragment

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thread_layout, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ThreadAsyncTask threads = new ThreadAsyncTask(addressOfThread);
        threads.execute();
        tv.setText(threads.getResulf());
        return view;
    }

}
```

and my AsyncTask

```
public class ThreadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String addressOfThread = "";
    public String resulf = "aaaa";

    public ThreadAsyncTask(String url) {
        this.addressOfThread = url;

    }
    public String getResulf(){
        return new String(this.result);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't implemented AsyncTask methods like doInBackground(). You have nothing in  getResulf()

Comment: aside from you not implementing the appropriate methods for an asynctask you also do not get the result of an asynctask that way. onPostExecute is where you get the result

Comment: I handle code in doinBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override `doInBackground` method to get/handling your data.
**This data** is available in `onPostExecute` method and from here, call back it to your UI (Activity or Fragment).
Please see my example gits to understand this process:
AsyncTask: https://gist.github.com/hongthaiis/77a847d2011f627c2c60#file-getweatherdatatask-java
Activity with call back method: https://gist.github.com/hongthaiis/43477678bb2764cfc0f6#file-weatheractivity-java

Hope this help! :D

Comment: thank everybody... iam so happy because you help me fix bug. and i was fixed it on last night, but iam lazy, so sory :P
i use get() method of doinbackgroud to get data when doinbackgroud finish....thank u

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement doInBackground method, in this method you need to specify the operations you want the task to execute in a separate thread. 
After this if you need to modify the UI with the result you obtained from doInBaackground, you have to implement the metod onPostExecute.

Comment: (Asytask) http://upfile.vn/xmIQMkBtFrXt/threadasynctask-java.html and (Fragment) http://upfile.vn/6TBtFrXtymIg/threadfragment-java.html .....thank u, can you check it

Comment: thank everybody... iam so happy because you help me fix bug. and i was fixed it on last night, but iam lazy, so sory :P
i use get() method of doinbackgroud to get data when doinbackgroud finish....thank u